# Battery discharge rate - serial vs solo

Tags: batteries, discharge

Suppose I had two deep-cycle 12 V batteries wired as shown and pulled a constant current as shown from each of the voltage points. Would the two batteries discharge evenly? Why or why not?

[image]

Comment: even without the 12V 40A load, they can be unbalanced and the weaker one will drain 1st

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect in series, as shown.

Then use a 24V to 12V converter.

That is exactly how I did my son’s tiny house power supply. He also has solar panels, 2 inverters and lights.

Answer (score 1):

You would be discharging one battery at 2A and the other at 42A. Not evenly.